# Why creates double variable passing argument?

Tags: debugging, typescript

I have same module ts

```
    export class Ingredient {
    public name: string;
    public amount: number;

    constructor(public pname: string, public pamount: number){
        this.name = pname;
        this.amount = pamount;
    }
   }
```

and in comonen.ts i have array Ingredients

```
ingredients: Ingredient[] = [new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
new Ingredient('Tomatoes', 2),
new Ingredient('Olives', 3),
new Ingredient('Onion', 4)
```

];

I debug and noticed something like that:

```
    0:
Ingredient
 pname:
Apples
 pamount:
5
 name:
Apples
 amount:
5
```

I don't understand why it's created pname and name variable? How to do to create only variable name and amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is creating those properties, since you marked them as `public`.

Using the `public` keyword in the constructor, is essentially a "shortcut" way of creating public properties, that are automatically assigned from the constructor arguments. So the code:

```
export class Ingredient {
    constructor(public pname: string, public pamount: number){
    }
}
```

Is basically equivalent to:

```
export class Ingredient {
    public pname: string;
    public pamount: number;

    constructor(pname: string, pamount: number){
        this.pname = pname;
        this.pamount = pamount;
    }
}
```

So what you really want is just this:

```
export class Ingredient {
    constructor(public name: string, public amount: number){ }
}
```

and you should be good to go. The feature is called **Parameter Properties** and is [well hidden in the official documentation.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties)

Comment: it's work thanks. I have a one more question if constructor is shortcut way of creating public properties why if i will leave variable with default modifier in class and use public in constructor it also create double variable ?

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure I understand this second question. If you have the same property declaration in both the class body and the constructor, the typescript compiler should throw a "duplicate property" error.